# specify the whole SDO_GEOMETRY as NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, geometry

would appreciate any pointers on this, am getting an error message - Action:   Verify that the geometries have valid fields. To specify a `NULL` geometry, specify the whole `SDO_GEOMETRY` as `NULL` instead of setting each field to `NULL`.

Some of my Longtitudes and Latitudes may be missing, how do I change my code to set the whole of `SDO_GEOMETRY` to `NULL` as it asks ? Thanks Gav

```
sdo_geom.sdo_distance(sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(2001, 8307, 
                                            sdo_geom.sdo_point_type(PC.LATITUDE, PC.LONGITUDE, NULL), NULL, NULL),                               
                      sdo_geom.sdo_geometry(2001, 8307, 
                                            sdo_point_type(ENR."End Venue Latitude", ENR."End Venue Longitude", NULL), NULL, NULL)
                    , 0.0001, 'unit=M') DISTANCE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very far from being any kind of an expert here, but - if you are **verifying** whether geometries are valid or not, how about this ("`geom`" is a table column whose datatype is `SDO_GEOMETRY`):

```
select *
from your_table
where sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context (geom, .05) <> 'TRUE';
```